# Linq to XML, retrieving list from like names elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some XML, that I am stuck with.

I am not certain how to retrieve from this format. I'm considering generating an integer and performing a loop based on string concatenation, but I'm hoping someone has done something similar and found a more clever solution.

**XML**

```
<TRANSACTION>
  <!-- Not ideal, but fairly straight forward. -->
  <itema></itema>
  <itemb></itemb>
  <itemtypea></itemtypea>
  <itemtypeb></itemtypeb>
  <itemid></itemid>
  <itemlabeltypea></itemlabeltypea>
  <itemlabeltypeb></itemlabeltypeb>
  <savenewitema></savenewitema>
  <savenewitemb></savenewitemb>
  <!-- One to Many Inserts: Insert0, Insert1, etc. -->
  <Insert0></Insert0>
  <InsertinItem0></InsertinItem0>
  <!-- One to Many Deletes: Again, seriously? -->
  <Delete0></Delete0>
  <DeletefromItem0></DeletefromItem0>
  <!-- One to Many Updates: Why? -->
  <Update0></Update0>
  <UpdateinItem0></UpdateinItem0>
</TRANSACTION>
```

Linq to XML

```
// Create data object from XML.
var data = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("TRANSACTION")
            select new
            {
                // Pseudo code, this will undesirably retrieve Delete0 and DeletefromItem0 as separate records.
                // Perhaps a join is necessary and I need to filter out DeletefromItem0 from the left hand table?
                // Are there any obvious solutions I may have missed?
                DeleteFromItems = from e in item.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Delete"))
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      ItemId = default(int), // Would ideally contain DeletefromItem0.
                                      UniqueId = e.Value
                                  },
                InsertIntoItems = from e in item.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Insert"))
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      ItemId = default(int),
                                      UniqueId = e.Value
                                  },
                ItemId = item.Element("itemid").Value,
                PrimaryItem = new
                {
                    Id = Int32.Parse(item.Element("itema").Value),
                    IsNew = Boolean.Parse(item.Element("savenewitema").Value),
                    LabelType = item.Element("itemlabeltypea").Value,
                    Type = item.Element("itemtypea").Value
                },
                SecondaryItem = new
                {
                    Id = Int32.Parse(item.Element("itemb").Value),
                    IsNew = Boolean.Parse(item.Element("savenewitemb").Value),
                    LabelType = item.Element("itemlabeltypeb").Value,
                    Type = item.Element("itemtypeb").Value
                }
            }).First();
```

Comment: Czech out JSON.NET, which, despite its name, also works with XML.

Comment: You should look into getting the author of that XML to put the data in a sane XML format. Also get them a book, slap them across the head, something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do yourself a big favor and sanitize the document before trying to consume it.  You could probably do this in XSLT but you'll probably have a tough time.  Fortunately, it isn't the worst using good 'ol LINQ.

While not strictly necessary, it would be a good idea to track any sanitized elements to make sure that they're not processed multiple times.

```
public static class XmlSanitizer
{
    static XNamespace NS => "urn:example:sanitizer";
    internal static XName IndexName => NS + "Index";
    internal static XName SanitizedName => NS + "Sanitized";

    public static void Sanitize(XDocument doc, params string[] patterns)
    {
        if (!HasSanitzerNamespace(doc))
            doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "s", NS.NamespaceName));

        foreach (var pattern in patterns)
        {
            var nodes =
                (from e in doc.Root.Elements()
                let m = Regex.Match(e.Name.LocalName, pattern)
                where m.Success
                let sanitized = (bool?)e.Attribute(SanitizedName)
                where !(sanitized ?? false)
                select new
                {
                    Element = e,
                    Namespace = e.Name.Namespace,
                    LocalName = m.Groups[1].Value,
                    Index = m.Groups[2].Value,
                }).ToList();
            foreach (var x in nodes)
            {
                // it might be preferrable to place the new elements within a grouping element
                x.Element.ReplaceWith(
                    new XElement(x.Namespace + x.LocalName,
                        new XAttribute(IndexName, x.Index),
                        new XAttribute(SanitizedName, true),
                        x.Element.Attributes(),
                        x.Element.Nodes()
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }

    static bool HasSanitzerNamespace(XDocument doc) =>
        (from a in doc.Root.Attributes()
        where a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.Xmlns
        where (string)a == NS.NamespaceName
        select a).Any();
}

public static class XmlStanitizerExtensions
{
    static XName IndexName => XmlSanitizer.IndexName;
    public static XElement ElementIndex(this XElement e, XName name, string index) => e.Elements(name).Where(n => (string)n.Attribute(IndexName) == index).Single();
}
```

Then to sanitize, pass in a regular expression for the names to group

```
XmlSanitizer.Sanitize(doc, new string[]
{
    @"(item)([ab])",
    @"(itemtype)([ab])",
    @"(itemlabeltype)([ab])",
    @"(savenewitem)([ab])",
    @"(Insert)(\d+)",
    @"(InsertinItem)(\d+)",
    @"(Delete)(\d+)",
    @"(DeletefromItem)(\d+)",
    @"(Update)(\d+)",
    @"(UpdateinItem)(\d+)",
});
```

This will give you something like this:

```
<TRANSACTION xmlns:s="urn:example:sanitizer">
  <!-- Not ideal, but fairly straight forward. -->
  <item s:Index="a" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <item s:Index="b" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <itemtype s:Index="a" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <itemtype s:Index="b" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <itemid></itemid>
  <itemlabeltype s:Index="a" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <itemlabeltype s:Index="b" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <item s:Index="a" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <item s:Index="b" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <!-- One to Many Inserts: Insert0, Insert1, etc. -->
  <Insert s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <InsertinItem s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <!-- One to Many Deletes: Again, seriously? -->
  <Delete s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <DeletefromItem s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <!-- One to Many Updates: Why? -->
  <Update s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
  <UpdateinItem s:Index="0" s:Sanitized="true" />
</TRANSACTION>
```

At least with this, processing will be easier to do.

```
var data =
    (from t in doc.Elements("TRANSACTION")
    select new
    {
        // assuming the indices are sequential
        DeleteFromItems = t.Elements("Delete").Zip(t.Elements("DeletefromItem"), (d, dfi) => new
            {
                ItemId = (int)dfi, // assuming there's a value
                UniqueId = (string)d,
            }).ToList(),
        InsertIntoItems = t.Elements("Insert").Zip(t.Elements("InsertinItem"), (i, iii) => new
            {
                ItemId = (int)iii, // assuming there's a value
                UniqueId = (string)i,
            }).ToList(),
        UpdateIntoItems = t.Elements("Update").Zip(t.Elements("UpdateinItem"), (u, uii) => new
            {
                ItemId = (int)uii, // assuming there's a value
                UniqueId = (string)u,
            }).ToList(),
        ItemId = (string)t.Element("itemid"),
        PrimaryItem = new
        {
            Id = (int)t.ElementIndex("item", "a"),
            IsNew = (bool)t.ElementIndex("savenewitem", "a"),
            LabelType = (string)t.ElementIndex("itemlabeltype", "a"),
            Type = (string)t.ElementIndex("itemtype", "a"),
        },
        SecondaryItem = new
        {
            Id = (int)t.ElementIndex("item", "b"),
            IsNew = (bool)t.ElementIndex("savenewitem", "b"),
            LabelType = (string)t.ElementIndex("itemlabeltype", "b"),
            Type = (string)t.ElementIndex("itemtype", "b"),
        },
    }).Single();
```

Additionally, I would group corresponding elements during the sanitation phase to make processing a lot more easier.  Then you wouldn't have to make a lot of the assumptions about the data.  I'll leave that to you as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this extension method might make working with this sort of data easier:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> EnumerateGroup(this XElement source, string groupName)
{
    return source.Elements()
        .Where(element => Regex.IsMatch(element.Name.LocalName, "^" + groupName + "[a-z0-9]*$"));
}
```

Used as:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var results = xml.EnumerateGroup("savenewitem"); // savenewitema, savenewitemb
```

The method enumerates all child elements but the regex (a topic entirely unto itself if you are not familiar with it, plenty of good resources here though) will only return the ones that match the group name exactly. Or, if there is a single extra character on the end (from looking at your examples of a,b 0 etc - you may need to extend this if you have larger numbers!).

Comment: If I understand your code it looks like this could provide the filter, but I would still need to join the zero on the zero somehow? In order to tie both properties back to a single object?